# Return RGB object instead of string from d3 scale and color interpolation

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am using `d3-scale` and `d3-scale-chromatic` to generate a color scale. It is working well but the result is a css string like `"rgb(100, 122, 222)"`.

Because I am working in a WebGL context I don't need to get the css string, I use the rgb values directly. It's too bad because I need to convert this string back into an object and I see that the [D3 interpolate module](https://github.com/d3/d3-interpolate/blob/0c026b4603f594ef6863cf22fc122b62c00a8633/src/rgb.js#L49) is already computing an rgb object like I need before casting it into a string.

I wanted to know if it's possible to bypass this conversion and get the object directly from D3?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`d3.color`](https://github.com/d3/d3-color/blob/v1.2.3/README.md#color), which:

> Parses the specified CSS Color Module Level 3 specifier string, returning an RGB or HSL color.

For instance, suppose you have this string:

```js
const colorString = d3.interpolateSpectral(0.5);
console.log(colorString)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

By passing it to `d3.color`, you can get the `r`, `g`, `b` and `opacity` properties:

```js
const colorString = d3.interpolateSpectral(0.5);
const colorObject = d3.color(colorString);
console.log(colorObject)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact is not about parsing the rgb string, it's more about performance, because d3 generate first ( internally ) the rgb object and then cast it to a string.  Because i need the rgb object i was asking if it is possible to have a custom interpolator that return the rgb object direclty

Comment: Yes, you can have a custom interpolator, just change the source code to generate the object you want.